# What i am doing wrong? Excel lock range

Tags: excel, vba, range, locking

What i am doing wrong?
I get error "impossible to set range property "locked"

```
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For j = 1 To 2000
    For k = 1 To 500
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(j, k).Interior.color = color Then                  
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(j, k),     
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(j, k)).Locked = False
    Next k
    Next j
    Next i
```

Am i missing some links between range and cells?

Comment: You cannot set/change the `locked`-property of a range if the sheet itself is already protected and the range is already locked.

Comment: If i have a key for the wardrobe in a flat, but the flat is closed, then first i have to open the door of the flat to get to the wardrobe.

Comment: Btw: Do you want to enable for cells with a specific color: Are those cells really formatted with red or it the color set by conditional formatting?

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(j, k),     
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(j, k))` equals to `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(j, k)`.

Answer (score 0):

modify your code to properly work with locked cells:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Unprotect ' Unprotect the worksheet
    
    For j = 1 To 2000
        For k = 1 To 500
            If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(j, k).Interior.Color = color Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(j, k).Locked = False
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Protect ' Protect the worksheet again
Next i
```

In this modified code, I've added Unprotect before making changes to cell properties and Protect after the changes. This ensures that you can modify the "Locked" property of cells without encountering the error.

Just replace 'color' in your code with the actual value you are using to compare cell interior colors. Also, remember that protecting and unprotecting a worksheet may require a password if the worksheet is password-protected.